# Error reported while running Laucher by chisel

Tags: chisel

I downloaded the chisel-tutorial which is offered on the website of usb-bar.
In order to do practise I created a scala file named as "Regfile.scala" under the path:

```
"chisel-tutorial/src/main/scala/solutions/Regfile.scala".
```

The Test-file is stored under the path :

```
"chisel-tutorial/src/test/scala/solutions/RegfileTests.scala".
```

While running the sbt I was reported

```
(after execution of command  "test:run-main solutions.Launcher Regfile"):

"Errors: 1: in the following tutorials
 Bad tutorial name: Regfile "
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your Regfile to Launcher.scala. The launcher is available in directory :

```
src/test/scala/solutions/Launcher.scala
```

I think you can add somethings like this to Launch.scala to test your Regfile:

```
"Regfile" -> { (backendName: String) =>
  Driver(() => new Regfile(), backendName) {
    (c) => new RegfileTests(c)
  }
},
```